# On the definition of tilting of a perfectoid field

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations

Given a perfectoid field $K$, for example $\widehat{\mathbf{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^{\infty}})}, \widehat{\mathbf{Q}_p(p^{1/p^{\infty}})}$ or $\widehat{\mathbf{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^{\infty}}, p^{1/p^{\infty}})}$.  According to [Bhatt's lecture note](https://websites.umich.edu/%7Ebhattb/teaching/mat679w17/lectures.pdf) ( If I understand correct, see for example section 3.2), seems we have to first define the tilting of the ring of integer $K^{\circ\flat}$, then define $K^{\flat}$ to be the fraction field of the former, or more precisely invert certain element $t$ (see for example Prop 3.2.4). While on the other hand, notice there is a more "direct?" way to define the "tilting" directly as
$\varprojlim_{\phi}K$ (If I am correct, this is exactly the $R(E)$ defined in  [the original paper of Wintenberger](http://www.numdam.org/item/10.24033/asens.1440.pdf) :see section 4.1)

**Remark:** Sure, you can not see directly what is the addition: in priori $\varprojlim_{\phi}K$ is only a multiplicative monoid, while the fact that there is a bijection $\varprojlim_{\phi}O_K/p\simeq \varprojlim_{\phi} O_K$ help us to "transfer" the addition structure from the former to the latter (via this bijection). But as in [the original paper of Wintenberger](http://www.numdam.org/item/10.24033/asens.1440.pdf) section 4.1, you can just formally define that addition: $(x_n)+(y_n):=(z_n)$ with $z_n:=\lim_m(x_{n+m}+y_{n+m})^{p^m}$, to make it a characteristic $p$ field.

> **Question:** Do these two definitions coincide? More
> precisely, do we have $Frac(\varprojlim_{\phi}O_K) \simeq \varprojlim_{\phi}K$?

**Remark:** There is an injective map (from left to right): it suffices to map $\frac{1}{y}$ for any $y=(y_n)_{n\in\mathbf{N}}\in (O_K)^{\flat}$, to $(\frac{1}{y_n})_{n\in \mathbf{N}}\in \varprojlim_{\phi}K$. While for the surjectivity  it is a little subtle: take any $z=(z_n)_n\in \varprojlim_{\phi}K$, we can write $z_0=\frac{x_0}{y_0}$, and in our case we can construct $x=(x_n)_n$ and $y=(y_n)_n\in (O_K)^{\flat}$ and expect $x/y$ is a preimage. But then you notice, first position is by construction $\frac{x_0}{y_0}=z_0$, good, but the second position is $\frac{x_1}{y_1}$ which is indeed a $p$-th root of $z_0$, but not necessarily the $z_1$ (Notice if we were working in characteristic $p$, then they must coincide $z_1=\frac{x_1}{y_1}$ as "$x^p=y^p \Longleftrightarrow x=y$ in char $p$"). Is this indeed THE problem, or actually we can fix that?

Comment: Notice that Scholze's original paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.4914.pdf) defines (see Definition 1.2) exactly as Fontaine and Wintenberger did. So the answer to my question should be yes, and it should be an exercise to show the surjectivity.

Comment: Further remark, this is exactly Lemma 3.4 (iii) in the same paper  (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.4914.pdf). Actually, different from the map I used in my last remark, the untilting functor $x\mapsto x^{\sharp}$ is used and the map constructed is then $x=(x_n)_n\mapsto (x^{\sharp}, (x^{1/p})^{\sharp}, \cdots)$. Actually this is just a slight modification of proving that mentioned fact $\varprojlim_{\phi}O_K/p\simeq \varprojlim_{\phi}O_K$.

Comment: I think perfectoid algebra is definitely beyond the scope of MSE. Your question will probably be better-received on MathOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I summarize my comment as an answer. Basically this is exactly Lemma 3.4 (iii) in the paper [Scholze's original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.4914.pdf).

We first construct $\varprojlim\limits_{x\to x^p}O_K/p\to O_K, x=(\overline{x_n})_n\mapsto x^{\sharp}:=\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}x_n^{p^n}$ where $x_n$ is any lift from $O_K/p$ to $O_K$. Actually this limit exists and is independent of choice of lifts.

Now we construct $\varprojlim\limits_{x\to x^p}O_K/p\to \varprojlim\limits_{x\to x^p}O_K$, we construct the map $x\mapsto (x^{\sharp}, (x^{\sharp})^{1/p},(x^{\sharp})^{1/p^2}, \cdots)$
and because $x\mapsto x^{\sharp}$ is multiplicative, this extends to $(-)^{\sharp}: Frac(\varprojlim\limits_{x\to x^p}O_K/p)\to \varprojlim\limits_{x\to x^p}K$. We call the componentwise mod $p$ from right to left $\mathsf{Proj}$, and one checks this two map are inverse to each other.

Indeed, let's check the less obvious direction (corresponds to the surjectivity): $(-)^{\sharp}\circ \mathsf{Proj}=\mathsf{Id}$. Take $x=(x_0, x_1, x_2, \cdots)$ from the RHS, then we check $(-)^{\sharp}\circ \mathsf{Proj}(x)=x$. Let's compute the $m$-th position: by construction it is

> $(x^{\sharp})^{1/p^m}=\lim_n\widetilde{x_n}^{p^{n-m}}=\lim_s\widetilde{x_{m+s}}^{p^s}=x_m$

(we use $\widetilde{x_t}$ to denote an arbitrary lift of $\overline{x_t}$ to $O_K$): the last equality comes from the fact we are in a $p$-adic complete ring plus the observation ($x\equiv y$ mod $p) \Rightarrow (x^{p^n}\equiv y^{p^n}$ mod $p^n$).

---

Summary："In characteristic $0$, mod $p$ indeed lose information, but if you know mod $p$ of all its $p$-power roots, then you don't lose information (in a $p$-adic complete ring)"